# Setting print scaled factor of map in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, printing

I want to print a large area map in QGIS with 1:50000 scale but I need to fit it in 30 inches paper. How can i zoom out the map and retain its 1:50000 scale so that it will fit in my paper?

1) This is scaled in 1:50000

[image]

2) and this is zoomed out in 75% but the scale is still 1:50000

[image]

Comment: It is not possible. I think you don't understand a map scale. Your topo map made in 1:50000 scale. You have to enlarge output map to fit the basic map. If you look at two images you will see that your maps have different sizes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the idea is i just want to print 1:50000 map but compress in 75% zoomed out so that i can print larger area but i will retain the features of 1:50 000.

Comment: So you want to keep the same map *extent* while covering a larger print area?

Comment: Yes i want to spare and maximize the paper size with thesame map scale.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the "zoom" of a map, you basically change the scale. I explain :

You don't have the same scale in yours differents maps, because for the same distance in the pictures you represent diferrents distances in the reality.

So I understood that you ask for seems impossible.

You have 2 options :

1. change the format of your prints
2. change the format of your scale